# Problem when loading existing model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I generate a tensorflow model in another machine and my model folder has the contents:

```
-model.meta
-checkpoint
-model.index
-model.data-00000-of-00001
```

After copying it to my work machine I load the model using:

```
model1 = tf.train.import_meta_graph("models/model_epoch100_emb100_bs32_lr0.025/.meta")
model1.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint("models/model_epoch100_emb100_bs32_lr0.025/"))
```

This method used to work for another older model that I had. However now I get this error:

```
ERROR:tensorflow:Couldn't match files for checkpoint models/model_epoch100_emb100_bs32_lr0.025/.
ERROR:tensorflow:Couldn't match files for checkpoint models/model_epoch100_emb100_bs32_lr0.025/.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/datadisk/Workspace/project/fgsm.py", line 148, in <module>
    main(config)
  File "/datadisk/Workspace/project/fgsm.py", line 76, in main
    model1.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint("models/model_epoch100_emb100_bs32_lr0.025/"))
  File "/datadisk/Workspace/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1534, in restore
    raise ValueError("Can't load save_path when it is None.")
ValueError: Can't load save_path when it is None.
```

I have made sure that the path really exists and I have marked the folders as source in my intellij environment. I am at a loss at what could be wrong.

Edit:

I originally stored the model using:

```
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        save_path = saver.save(sess=sess, save_path="g2v_model/model")
```

But I copied the content of the folder and scp in my local machine in the aforementioned folder.

Edit2:

I don't know how relevant this is but there is also one thing. The code I generated the model was using python2 whereas the code I am using now is python 3.

Comment: can you try add 'path=os.path.realpath("models/model_epoch100_emb100_bs32_lr0.025/")' than run other functions with path variable

Comment: I did. The path exists. The problem is the checkpoint. I lifted this model from another machine to my local one.